# 2 equivalent definitions of differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I learned in class that to prove by definition the differentiability in(a,b) of a function $f$  we need to show that $f$ can be presented as :

(*)$f(k+a,t+b) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t = \epsilon(k,t)\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}$
for $\epsilon \rightarrow0$ as $k,t \rightarrow 0$

but then I saw this definition in one of the solutions (it was presented as definition):

(**)
$f$ is differentiable if:
$\lim_{k,t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(k,t) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t}{\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}} = 0$

I do understand that $(*)\Rightarrow (**)$, but I am not sure if I am correct about the other way:

Is it because $\epsilon$ epsilon is $\frac{f(k,t) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t}{\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}}$?

And if not, why does $(**)\Rightarrow (*)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. As you said, simply choose

$$\epsilon(k,t)=\frac{f(k,t) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t}{\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}}$$

for $(k,t)\not=(0,0)$, which then satisfies your version $(*)$.

$$\lim_{k,t\to 0} \epsilon(k,t)=\lim_{k,t\to 0} \frac{f(k,t) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t}{\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}}=0.$$

Comment: Okay, thanks! But what happens if this $\epsilon$ diverges? Why does that imply that such $\epsilon$ does not exist, and therefore $f$ isn't differentiable in (a,b)?

Comment: @theshopen I am not sure what you mean. It seems you want to prove $\neg (*)\implies \neg(**)$, which is true, but equivalent to $(**)\implies (*)$ (which is true as seen from my answer) by simple logic, no analysis involved. The fact that this limit exists *proves* that the $\epsilon$ defined this way cannot diverge.

Comment: I understood the logic, I'll rephrase my question. 
Is the following nerative ok? :

Assume such $\epsilon$ exist. So it implies that$$\lim_{k,t\to 0} \epsilon(k,t)=\lim_{k,t\to 0} \frac{f(k,t) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t}{\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}}=0.$$ But if the $\lim$ outcome isn't 0, then such epsilon cannot exist and therefore the function isn't differentiable in (a,b)

Comment: @theshopen Let's do it step by step. I assume you want to argue for $(**)\implies (*)$ (is this right? At some points it feels like you want to do both directions at once). In this case you do *not assume* that $\epsilon$ exists, but you *construct* an appropriate $\epsilon$, because you already know that the limit exists (this is $(**)$).

Comment: And what if I wanted $\neg (*) \Rightarrow \neg(**)$. Will the nerattive I explained in the comment above will be okay?

Comment: @theshopen To be honest, to prove $\neg(*)\implies\neg(**)$ I would go by "proof by contradiction" which gives $(**)\implies (*)$. I have no idea how to show $\neg(*)\implies\neg(**)$ directly, and I am not sure this is possible.

Comment: Thanks so much. You really helped :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79626/discussion-between-theshopen-and-m-winter).

Answer (score 0):

If $(**)$, then you *define* $\varepsilon(x,y)$ as$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{f(k,t) -f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)k-f_y(a,b)t}{\sqrt{k^2 +t^2}}&\text{ if }(k,t)\neq(0,0)\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$and then $\lim_{(k,t)\to(0,0)}\varepsilon(k,t)=0$ and $(*)$ holds.